# Add MS Planner tab to group chat in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, trello, microsoft-planner

How do I add a Microsoft Planner tab to a group chat in Microsoft Teams?

I can add a Atlassian Trello tab to group chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default

> Owners and team members can add tabs to a channel, private chat, and
>   group chat to help integrate their cloud services. Tabs can be added
>   to help users easily access and manage the data they need or interact
>   with the most.

For some reason some of the apps are not appearing in Group chat.

But I have carefully checked the channels and private chat. I can able to add the planner app. For Group chat certainly some updates /settings are missing.

However the solution for your question is. ( Bit of hacky way) But it can work

1. Create a Group Chat with your team members
2. Hit the `+` tab and Select website. Please see screen shot below

[image]

3. Enter your Tab name as "MS Planner" and in the URL `https://tasks.office.com/` add the link
4. Select the checkbox "Post to the chat about this tab" so that your other group chat members know

[image]

5. When you hit save you should be definitely seeing the Planner > Signin and start using it.
6. Here is the confirmation

[image]

**Hope it helps.**